# Laravel route() and url() functions return wrong subdomain

Tags: php, apache, laravel, docker

I'm creating test application with Laravel and Docker.

[image: Docker containers]

I have 3 Docker containers: one Apache which using `ProxyPass` selecting one of other two containers and two containers which have Laravel applications.

I have also extra lines in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1        auth.pi
127.0.0.1        worker.pi
```

My main (green) Apache's conf file is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName auth.pi

    ProxyPass / http://auth:80/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName worker.pi

    ProxyPass / http://worker:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

In red's `.env I have

```
APP_URL=http://auth.pi
```

But when I used `url('/')` or `route(...)` my domain is `http://auth/`.

My red's Apache's conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName auth.pi

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html/public">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

File `docker-compose.yml` contains:

```
services:
  apache:
    build: "./apache"
    container_name: "pi-apache"
    links:
      - "auth-apache:auth"
    ...
  auth-apache:
    build: "./applications/auth/apache"
    container_name: "pi-auth-apache"
    ...
```

What I do wrong? Why my red's Laravel app thinks that he is `http://auth/` not `http://auth.pi/`?

In blue's app I have same configuration and same issue.

Comment: Update your `docker-compose` file with [hostname](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir) so that containers can know what their hostname is.

Comment: @Ayushya I added `domainname: "auth.pi"` and `hostname: "auth"` in `auth-apache` service but this not helps.

Comment: Hostname should be able to identify containers as said in descriptions about [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases) you might not be accessing it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with green's conf

In `VirtualHost` section I must add

```
RequestHeader set Host "auth.pi"

ProxyPreserveHost On
```

Final `VirtualHost` for `auth.pi`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName auth.pi

    RequestHeader set Host "auth.pi"

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://auth:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added in `docker-compose.yml`

```
  auth-apache:
    build: "./applications/auth/apache"
    container_name: "pi-auth-apache"
    domainname: "pi"
    hostname: "auth"
    ...
```